# how to create window service and use for sending mail

Tags: c#

i m creating a library project and want to sending mail automatically for the defaulter(who not return book at time) . for some search on internet i found the window service that help
but i can't understand to use properly
1- create a window service with timer that compare current date to sqltable returndate column
(how to compare)
and if (is true)
then send mail automatically.
please tell me ho how  to implement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a new service project (**Visual C# / Windows / Windows service**)
2. Double click on the **service file** in **solution explorer**.
3. Right click in the design view of that file and **add an installer** from the context menu.
4. Select the **service process installer** item in the design view and setup the ***Account* property** in the Properties window to something like **NetworkService** or **LocalSytem** to give the service enough rights for mail network and database operations
5. In the underlying service class you have the overwritten methods **OnStart()** and **OnStop()** to control the behavior of the service. you also can overwrite **OnPause()**, **OnShutdown()** and **OnContinue()**
6. Use the **SmtpClient** class from the .NET Framework, if you want to send by SMTP: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx
7. Use the console tool **installutil.exe** from the .NET SDK to install the service:

   installutil.exe -i myService.exe

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I needed this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Since you already  probably have the data in SQL, use the built-in db-mail functionality: [Database Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175887.aspx).

Simply have a daily SQL Agent job that scans the table for delinquents and calls [sp_send_dbmail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx) for each.